# React with Webpack: PropTypes appearing in final bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Per [React's documentation on PropTypes](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#static-proptypes):

> Note that for performance reasons `propTypes` is only checked in development mode.

However, when I build my app with Webpack, I see the propTypes that I have defined still in the final bundle.

I am setting the NODE_ENV to production. Is this behavior expected?

My theory:

The PropTypes validation is skipped, although the PropType definitions are still in production code. If this theory is correct, are there any best practices for stripping PropTypes in prod code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Babel plugin that does the trick:

https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types

Answer (score 0):

The `propTypes` on your own components are indeed kept in all builds, but not verified when React is built with `NODE_ENV` set to `production`.

What you could do is define your propTypes in the 'oldschool' way (not as class properties), and do that conditionally.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { ... }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    MyComponent.propTypes = {
        text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };
}
```

Webpack will evaluate the if to `if (false) { ... }` if you use the `DefinePlugin`, and Uglify will then remove it completely.

It doesn't exactly make the code any more beautiful and you can't extract the behaviour since it has to be explicit for Webpack and Uglify to do the removal, but it works.

The other, more advanced option would be writing your own Babel plugin, for example. There's [one out there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bloody-strip-proptypes) but it hasn't been updated for almost a year, so I doubt it still works with Babel 6. It's not complex though, and might be a fun exercise.

Comment: The Babel plugin route seems like the best way to go. I would give it a shot when I have some free time.

Comment: I'm curious to see what you'll work up, sounds like a useful plugin for minifying React apps!

Comment: Done! The one from bloodyowl was a very handy reference! https://github.com/avindra/react-strip-proptypes What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue. The babel plugin https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types doesn't work for me (doesn't have support for typescript).

The better "dirty hack" I've found:

```
MyComponent['propTypes'] = {...};
```

Comment: Being that [Babel supports Typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript), you could switch to Babel for your compilation and use the plugin. If you still want to enforce type checking, you can run `tsc` as an additional step.